# AWS Amplify deploy - use compression

Tags: compression, web-hosting, aws-amplify

We're using AWS Amplify to serve an Angular frontend via CI/CD (connected Github-Repo).
Amplify does not seem to compress by default resulting in larger content delivery than necessary.

I can't find any option in the app settings inside the Amplify dashboard nor a solution [online](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/343).

[image]

Is it possible to use compression (gzip or brotli) with AWS Amplify?

Comment: Did you find a solution? We have many sites running on Amplify, some of them are serving gzip files but some of them no. How do you solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>We managed to serve gziped responses and if i remember it correctly it was a setting hidden in the cloudfront configuration.</strike>

[image]

Altough i don't remember how i've activated that option, probably through the aws-cli.

---

**UPDATE: Amplify seems to serve gzip by default now**

Comment: I have the same settings. In my account, it is named "Amplify (Policy for Amplify Origin)" and it was there by default, prior to any deployment. I also verified that the browser is indeed receiving gzip content, which is the case (something like 280KB instead of 1.4MB in my case).

Comment: That makes me think that they changed the default behaviour and serve gzip'ed content without any additional settings (altough i can't find any resources online). 

Would be nice if any AWS employee could clarify this.

Comment: I'm not an AWS employe, but I can tell that I just deploy an Amplify app with CDK on a fresh new account, and GZIP was enabled by default.